# Get package dependencies size/count/amount for shields.io badge

Tags: package.json, shields.io

So far I got this: [https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axios/axios/master/package.json&query=$.dependencies[*]&label=dependecies](https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axios/axios/master/package.json&query=$.dependencies%5B*%5D&label=dependecies)

Maybe there is a way to convert object to array and then use `.length`?

Or maybe third party api which ether has dependencies in array or has number of dependencies

If it's not clear in case of `axios` which has 1 dependency I want to have this badge:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by JSONPath (yet). The `.length()` function can only be used to count items in an array, [see the relevant docs section here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions). In your case, you are trying to count items in an object.

> length()  Provides the length of an array